# keybord is not working in linux 18.04lts

Tags: linux

after installing an adobe photoshop CS6.My keyboard is not working properly and one Symbol is Start coming on my laptop. when I type this Symbol Comes. And there no problem with my mouse. it is working even this Symbol Comes. And now the laptop Starts Hanging.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2Zku.png) HOW TO GET RID OF THIS PROBLEM PLS TELL ME. it's very irritating.

Comment: Does your laptop have a hot key for disabling the keyboard? What about when you plug an external USB keyboard in?

Comment: are you talking about window key? the same thing is when i am using an external USB keyboard.

Comment: i have to change the operating system after facing this problem switching to the windows 10. After that i do face this problem.

Comment: You're saying you have the same problem in both Linux and Windows? Please use the EDIT button and add new or additional information to the body of the question, not comments.